# Is it safe to ignore xcuserdata?

Tags: xcode, github

Is it safe to add xcuserdata to gitignore file if you are working in team? It creates a lot of problem while pulling the other developer's branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's safe to ignore, or you can safely delete the xcuserdata directories. It basically contains personal settings like breakpoints, user interface layout, open files, automatic snapshots configuration and so on。